# Crontab -l command working. No other crontab command is working

Tags: macos, cron

New to crontab, I wanted to experiment.

Running the command `crontab -l` gave me the following answer `crontab: no crontab for User_1`

Every time I tried to issue a command like `1 16 24 10 6 ping -D -c 1 www.google.com` I got the error "zsh: command not found".

Every time I modified the first number of the crontab command I got an error message saying, if for example 15 is the first number of the command, `zsh: command not found: 15`.

For info:

Mac OS X 10.12.6.
zsh 5.8

`which crontab`: `/usr/bin/crontab`

`/usr/bin` is in my path.

Comment: `1 16 24 10 6 ping ...` will only run when Oct 24th falls on a Saturday. To make it run every year use `1 16 24 10 * ping ...`, to make it run each Saturday use `1 16 * * 6 ping ...`

Comment: I was testing the command, so I tried to run the command only one time just to see if it was working. I do not understand why when I issue the command ```crontab -l``` at 18:39 or later, I get the following answer ```38 18 24 10 6  echo "test" >> ~/Downloads/test.txt```. As the command has been run, shouldn't I get an answer saying no cron job is planned? I watched the Youtube Corey Schafer video about crontab and ```crontab -l``` is in his own words for "scheduled" jobs). Issuing ```crontab -r``` deinstalled this job from the crontab jobs list.

Comment: Your crontab file contains any commands/jobs you ever wanted to run via cron, even if their conditions will never be valid (you need to remove them manually from crontab). For one-off scheduling have a look at `man at`.

Comment: ```at``` looks very interesting! Tried it on my Mac. Worked. Unfortunately, it is deprecated. From developer.apple.com "Older approaches, such as at jobs and periodic jobs are deprecated and should not be used."

Comment: This applies to both cron and at, one should use launchd instead. But the notice is there since ages, and as cron/at can easily be installed from source if necessary I wouldn’t worry too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *edit* your crontab to make changes. Run

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

to use the `nano` editor for this. Your (initially empty) crontab will be shown and can be edited (e.g. by adding the line you had in your question). Then press <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> to save the changes and quit the editor.

Comment: OK, it is working now. Thank you! Is it fair to sum up the situation to "It couldn't work as your crontab command has to be in a crontab file to be working"?

Comment: @politicus True, the commands to be run by cron need to be in the crontab file.